# NSDecimalNumber(string: ".") returns 0 (zero). Why?

Tags: ios, string, swift3, nan, nsdecimalnumber

This is Swift 3, Xcode 8.1
I was expecting `nan`.

Would that be a bug?

To illustrate:

[image: Playground]

Any ideas on how to handle "."?
I'd like to avoid things like:

```
if string == "." { ... }

guard string =! "." { ... }
```

Comment: That is more of a feature than a bug. (why) do you want to explicitly exclude "." as valid input?

Comment: Curious - what happens with `NSDecimalNumber(string: ",")` (using a comma) if the device's locale is set to a locale that uses comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: @rmaddy That character must match the locale decimal separator `Decimal(string: ".", locale: Locale(identifier: "de"))` will return `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` is a valid input.

`0.` is a valid input`.

`.0` is a valid input.

It's not so surprising that `.` is also a valid input. Strange, but not surprising and the value is well defined.

Note this is valid only if the character matches current locale, e.g. `.` will work with the English locale but not with German locale and viceversa:

```
Decimal(string: ".", locale: Locale(identifier: "de")) // NaN
Decimal(string: ",", locale: Locale(identifier: "de")) // Optional(0)
```

In short, both leading and trailing zeros can be omitted.

If you want to handle this value, I recommend to use regular expressions. Decide which formats are valid, write a regular expression for that formats and check the string with that regular expression.

Comment: I disagree. You could have written your answer as: `5` is valid. `5.` is valid. `.5` is valid. That doesn't make `.` valid and it doesn't make it `0`.

Comment: @rmaddy My reasoning is that the leading or trailing zeros can be omitted. It's strange but I don't consider it a bug.

Comment: Another thing that looks weird to me: `nan` is also returned for `,` (expected) (just updated my Playground example). Following what you described, shouldn't it also return `0`?

Comment: @singledev As I said in the comment under your question, the decimal separator is taken from the locale. `,` is an invalid character in English locale. Parsing `2,5` would result in number `2`. However, if you change your locale to german (`de`), then `.` will be an invalid character and `,` will be the decimal separator.

Comment: @Sulthan I think that makes sense. Please add your comment (under my question) on using the proper Locale and I'll accept your answer. Thank you.